# automatically updating data using cloud code in Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I'm looking a method to automatically updating data using cloud code.

Let say I have a class `Table`.
inside of it, I have three column : `firstname`, `lastname`, and `fullname`.

Currently, I only have `firstname` and `lastname` data only. Column `fullname` is still empty.

Is it possible to fill the `fullname` automatically, by just combining the value in `firstname` and `lastname`?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@RoyH is 100% right to maintain your computed column as new objects are created.  To do an initial migration, try a cloud function, like:

```
var _ = require("underscore");

Parse.Cloud.define("addFullnames", function(request, response) {
    // useMasterKey if the calling user doesn't have permissions read or write to Table
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var query = new Parse.Query("Table");
    // we'll call tables > 1000  an 'advanced topic'
    query.limit = 1000;
    query.find().then(function(results) {
        _.each(results, function(result) {
            var firstname = result.get("firstname") || "";
            var lastname = result.get("lastname") || "";
            result.set("fullname", (firstname + " " + lastname).trim());
        });
        return Parse.Object.saveAll(results);
    }).then(function(results) {
        response.success(results);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Call it like this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: your_app_id_here" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: your_rest_key_here" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  https://api.parse.com/1/functions/addFullnames
```

You can factor out the code inside _.each() to make a function that's called here and by a beforeSave hook to maintain the data as it is added.

Comment: thank you for your help. I've tried your code, but i got this error message : `{"code":141,"error":"TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined\n    at main.js:11:40\n    at e (Parse.js:2:8151)\n    at Parse.js:2:7600\n    at Array.forEach (native)\n    at Object.x.each.x.forEach [as _arrayEach] (Parse.js:1:661)\n    at c.extend.resolve (Parse.js:2:7551)\n    at null.\u003canonymous\u003e (Parse.js:2:8230)\n    at e (Parse.js:2:8151)\n    at Parse.js:2:8904\n    at g (Parse.js:2:8641)"}`

Comment: Pls see edit. Make sure to require underscorejs which is really useful. Or replace the each with a native for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,  you can either just put a value for "fullname" when you are saving "firstname" and "lastname" (before cloudcode). Alternately, you can use the before save/ after save cloudcode functions to insert a value into that column:

Take a look at:

https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks-beforeSave
https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#webhooks-afterSave

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I forgot to mention that, I already got my data. So, I don't want to do "save the data". From my understanding, "afterSave" or "beforeSafe" will be execute every time "save the data" was execute. Is there any other method for this?