# How do I make my cloud code run on my worker dyno instead of web dyno?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

I have a parse server deployed on heroku. I am running some cloud code on my parse server its a code that takes several minutes to run and causes timeout errors on Heroku when run on a web dyno.

```
heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/parse/functions/timeScore
```

My understanding is if I can make the cloud code run on a worker dyno there won't be any timeout error. Is this correct?

So now I have a web and worker dyno running on my app.

[image]

And here is my `Procfile`

```
web: node index.js
worker: node bin/timeScoreJob
```

Is there anything else I need to do to run the cloud code on the worker dyno? As it currently does not run on the worker dyno. It runs on the web dyno as seen from the heroic logs when the code is running and I still get the timeout errors.

Here is how I run the cloud code from my terminal

```
heroku run node bin/timeScoreJob
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is my code not running on the worker dyno?

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but make sure that the has a node shebang `#!/usr/bin/env node` and make sure it has executable permission (chmod +x)

Comment: Hi, I did both of those but nothing changed. All heroku logs still start with app[web.1]: and all dyno is still web.1 (heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/parse/batch" host=randomapp.herokuapp.com request_id=d85cfc04-8a5e-4e5e-94ed-f9f0f9ba39f1 fwd="54.211.105.14" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=1588 protocol=http)

Comment: Also when I scale worker dyno to zero the code still runs the same way. Should it not give an error since there are no worker dynos available? And when I scale worker dyno to 1 I do get the following errors from worker logs heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to down. When worker dyno is 0 I dont get the crashed log.